# Get type parameter of super interface

Tags: java, generics

I have:

```
interface I<T> {}
```

and:

```
interface I1 extends I<Clazz1> {}
```

I have also I2, I3 and so on which extend I<Clazz2>, I<Clazz3> etc.

I don't know about Clazz1 in runtime. How could I get this information?

I tried:

```
subInterface1.getInterfaces()[0].getTypeParameters()[0]
```

but in only knows about T, not about Clazz1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
subInterface1.getInterfaces()[0].getTypeParameters()[0]
```

you are getting the first formal type parameter of the `Class` object representing the interface `I`, which is indeed the variable `T`.  Instead you need to use

```
subInterface1.getGenericInterfaces()[0]
```

to get the `Type` object representing the *particular instantiation* of `I` that has been extended by `I1`.  This will be an instance of `ParameterizedType`, so you can cast to that and then use `getRawType()` and `getActualTypeArguments()` to extract the raw type `I` and the *actual* type parameter value `Clazz1` respectively.  Note that the return type of `getActualTypeArguments()` is `Type[]` rather than `Class[]` because the actual arguments might not be concrete classes, they could be variables or wildcards (or indeed other parameterized types, in a case such as `List<List<String>>`).

Comment: Thanks. I've just found the similar solution. See my own answer.

Comment: But if they have in consistent sequnce, how to get the real type of `Clazz1`?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution:

```
((ParameterizedType)subInterface1.getGenericInterfaces()[0]).getActualTypeArguments()[0]
```